# borel-finite and non-negative measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu_y$ be a finite and non-negative measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mu$ a non-decreasing measure on $\mathbb{R}$, such that for every fixed $y\in (a,b)$ with $(a,b)$ *not* containing the origin
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}d\mu_y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-yt}d\mu(t)
$$
Under these assumptions is it possible to conclude that $\mu$ is borel-finite and non-negative? Thank you!

Comment: No is the short answer. Under your assumptions $\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\mu_y$ could be any positive function of $y$.